# How to access file from another application's directory on Bluemix?

Tags: r, directory, ibm-cloud

This is my problem scenario :

```
1.Create 2 apps.
2.App1 continuously pulls tweets and stores the json file in its /data folder.
3.App2  picks up the latest file from the /data folder of App1 and uses it.
```

I have used R and its corresponding build-pack to deploy the app on bluemix.

> How do I access /data/file1 in App1 from App2 i.e. can I do something like this in the App2 source file :
>
> > read.csv("App1/data/Filename.csv") ; 
> >     will bluemix understand what App1 folder points to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluemix is a Platform as a Service. This essentially means that there is no filesystem in the traditional sense. Yes, your application "lives" in a file structure on a type of VM, but if you were to restage or redeploy your application at any time, changes to the filesystem will be lost.

The "right" way to handle this data that you have is to store it in a `NoSQL` database and point each app to this DB. Bluemix offers several options, depending on your needs.

`MongoDB` is probably one of the easier and more straight-forward DBs to use and understand. `Cloudant` is also very good and robust, but has a slightly higher learning curve.

Once you have this DB set up, you could poll it for new records periodically, or better yet, look into using WebSockets for pushing notifications from one app to the other in real-time.

Either way, click the `Catalog` link in the Bluemix main navigation and search for either of these services to provision and bind them to your app. You'll then need to reference them via the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment object, which you can learn more about [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/index-gentopic5.html#scenario_bind).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access files from another app on bluemix. You should use a database service like cloudant to store your json. Bind the same service to both apps.

Comment: Also, it's not good practice to store anything to disk when writing cloud applications. The file system should be treated as ephemeral. Even a simple restart of the app will cause you lose your data.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But can this be done on R. i.e. App1 pushes json to cloudant and App2 retrieves file from cloudant for processing ?

Answer (score 0):

Using something like Cloudant or the Object Storage service would be a great way to share data between two apps.  You can even bind the same service to 2 apps.

Another solution would be to create a microservice that is your persistance layer that stores your data for you.  You could then create an API on top of this that both of your apps could call.

As stated above storing information on disk is not a good idea for a cloud app.  Go check out http://12factor.net, it describes no-no's for writing a true cloud based app.